# how to use pipe in a same process (thread safe)

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pipe

I'm trying to use pipe in the same process:

```
define MAX_SIZE 200

int read_port;
int send_port;

void init()
{

  int fd[2];

  pipe(fd);

  read_port = fd[0];

  send_port = fd[1];

}

void consume(void* destination) {

//read from pipe and store the content to destination

  read(read_port, destination, MAX_SIZE);

}

void channel_send(void* message) {

   write(send_port,message,MAX_SIZE)

}
```

There will be many threads to write to the pipe but only 1 thread to read from the pipe. Is there some potential problem in this code? The program sometimes is blocked because of some reason but I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: All pipes have a buffer, with a specific size. Any write less than or equal to this buffer size will be atomic.

Comment: If the problem happens while multithreading, we need to see the threading code as well. You could protect the write part with a semaphore (to make it atomic, re. comment from SPD)

Comment: @Some programmer dude, Less than the *remaining* buffer size, right?

Comment: You don't give much context, but I strongly suspect a datagram local socket created by `socketpair()` will be better suited to your needs than a stream-oriented pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code to a use POSIX semaphore to make the write operation a critical section

```
#include <semaphore.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 

sem_t mutex; 

void channel_send(void* message) {
   sem_wait(&mutex);
   write(send_port,message,MAX_SIZE);
   sem_post(&mutex); 
}
```

That makes the `write()` command atomic.